# Woocommerce price * quantity multiplication decimal issue

Tags: php, wordpress, woocommerce

I have some codes below that I share. I do price * quantity. Everything is good, however, If the result is XX,00 decimals do not appear.
If the result is XX,15 decimals appear.

```
$quantity   = apply_filters( 'woocommerce_cart_item_quantity', $cart_item['quantity'], $cart_item_key, $cart_item );
$price      = (float) wc_get_price_to_display( $product );
$result     = $quantity * $price;
```

As you understand. If the result is 12.15$ I can see decimals. If the result is 12.00$, I can't see decimals.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

that is because float doesn't show 0 ending decimals. Else you would see 12.15000... for example

So, use [number_format](https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.number-format.php)

in your case it is

```
$result=number_format($quantity*$price,2,'.','');
```

[image]

Comment: sorry nothing changed :/

Comment: make sure it is not recalculated anywhere else. This changes just current number, but if any operation is made with that value, that will become float again. So you should update that at the final point too

Comment: sorry nothing extra, maybe is there a way to add "00" to end, If decimals not higher than 0

Comment: just put die($result); after this. So that way you will see that it changes at this step and will go to dig next

Comment: I have put, but same result

Comment: I found the problem round($result,2) this remove decimals of 00. But I need to use round so what should i do?

Comment: $result1=round($quantity * $price, 2 );
$result=number_format($result1,2,'.','');  done thanks